# How to format fetched date in reactJS

Tags: reactjs

Hi I have fetched date/data but it showing like that "2022-05-14T14:00:00.000Z". How to convert this to 14/05/2022?

```
 <FetchedDate>
   {date}
 </FetchedDate>
```

Thank you for anyone help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

new Date(date).toLocaleDateString('en-GB');

[image]

Comment: It did not help. Doesn't work.

Comment: yes thank you this help more ! I really appreciate it. Currently its showing "10/05/2022, 17:03:34" so how I can get rid of the time?

Comment: Though it should not show time but you can add .split(',')[0] at the end. Please accept the answer if found helpful.